# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32') . What is the solution for this error?

Tags: python, machine-learning

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

This is the error coming, need what changes, type of variable change or something else?

Comment: You need to impute the values of all `np.NaN` and `np.inf`

Comment: There is no value Nan or inf its large data and this error happens when i train it with random forest classifier

Answer (score 1):

`df.fillna(value=0)` or whatever you want to fill it with, for details, check out:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html
or
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

For numbers too large for float32
`A='your numbers'
A=np.astype(float64)`
or
`A=int(A)`

what can also happen is that you merged two dataframes that are different in terms of columns counts or row counts. In this case, pandas will produce a dataframe that takes on the larger counts for columns and rows, then fill out the rest with Nan. If you check the dataframe with df.describe(), you should see.

Hope this to be helpful, sincerely.